# Remove user and ca certificate on Android 4.0

Tags: android, certificate

After two hours of research I'm wondering if there's a way to remove ca and user certificates from Android 4.0 (with root access).

- The android settings menu is very poor in function (doesn't even have a filter field) and doesn't delete
- The only certificate manager I found was CACertMan which hangs on loading certificates.

Any ideas?